# SSH Key / Password Issue

Tags: 12.04, ssh

I am running Ubuntu 12.04LTS.  I am trying to upload to github via SSH.  I generated my key using keygen, and made sure that github has the key as specified.  However, when I try to ssh in I keep getting a Ubuntu window opening asking for a password.  This is not coming from github, but from the Ubuntu system itself.  The keys are somehow password protected, which is fine, but I have absolutely no idea what that password might be.  It is not my root password.  It is not my user password.  I never actually set a password for those keys, so I am completely at a loss.  I've tried leaving it blank or just a space, but that doesn't work either.  I need to either find out what password this is, find a way to reset it to a password that I actually know, or somehow disable it.  The only posts I can find on this problem are much older ( 2008 ), and none of the files they talk about editing exist in 12.04.

Editing to clarify one more time.  This is a Ubuntu issue, not an SSH issue.  There is no issue with the key or the remote host.  The problem is with Ubuntu slapping a password on the use of this key without my knowledge and me having no idea what that password might be or how to reset / disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if this `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa/rsa.pub remote-host` works properly it will

append the keys to the remote-host’s `.ssh/authorized_key`

After that you should be able to login to that particular `remote-host` without password.

NB: Can you provide some more detail like how you added the key? Also yo can verify that from the user you've generated the key also trying to ssh from the same user.

## When no value is passed for the option -i and If ~/.ssh/identity.pub is not available, ssh-copy-id will display the following error message.

```
jsmith@local-host$ ssh-copy-id -i remote-host
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found
```

You may have a look into the Using `ssh-copy-id along with the ssh-add/ssh-agent` section of [This Link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/)

Comment: ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa/rsa.pub remote-host returns the error NO IDENTITIES FOUND.

Comment: As for more detail, I generated the keys using keygen.  What I am really looking for is exactly what password Ubuntu is looking for from me here.  I never set a password for my ssh keys.  It's not my root password.  It's not my login password.  I wouldn't mind entering the password if I had any way of knowing what password it wants me to enter.

Comment: And yes, I am trying to use ssh from the same user that generated the key.

Comment: @BlindFish Are you sure you didn't enter a passphrase when making the key? How about starting over, and making a new key?

Comment: Of course I entered a passphrase.  That is not what it's looking for.  I tried that several times.  It's as if the system is set to password protect the keys as a default, which is fine.  I totally get that.  I'm just blown away that it's not my root password.  I have no idea what the password could be or how to go about finding it.

Comment: @Suvasish: I have read that link several times.  You have to bear in mind that I'm not just trying to ssh between two servers that I own.  One happens to be a commercial server owned by someone else, in this case GitHub.  I have an account with them and my key is on file there.  They don't allow people to randomly slap their keys over just for funsies.  Here is [link](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)[/link] to how one goes about putting their key on github.  In fact, if you follow that the issue for me is Step 4.  Everything else is fine.    Step 4 throws the password box.